# why pandas concat gives me untrue dataframe while its type and shape is correct

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I want to make some language processing. my code work properly when I used dataframe that "yor1" or "yor2". but unfortunately when I merge these dataframe in 1 dataframe , which is "yorumlar", my code gives this error

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

and moreover to this, shape and type of "yorumlar" is true ü there is something wrong with pd.concat operation but i could'n solve it. all files ,that i try to concat, is same format. my code is

```
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import nltk
from nltk import FreqDist



yor1=pd.read_csv("Amazon Brand.csv")
yor2=pd.read_csv("American Soft Linen.csv")
yor3=pd.read_csv("GLAMBURG.csv")
yor4=pd.read_csv("Hammam.csv")
yor5=pd.read_csv("Hotel.csv")
yor6=pd.read_csv("Luxury Hotel.csv")
yor7=pd.read_csv("Luxury White.csv")
yor8=pd.read_csv("Qute.csv")



yorumlar = pd.concat([yor1,yor2,yor3,yor4,yor5,yor6,yor7,yor8], axis=0)
print(yorumlar)
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

ps=PorterStemmer()

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

#Preprocessing
derlem = []
allwords=[]

for i in range(yorumlar.shape[0]):
    yorum = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", yorumlar["Body"] [i])
  
    yorum=yorum.lower()

    yorum= yorum.split()
    yorum=[ps.stem(kelime) for kelime in yorum if not kelime in set(stopwords.words("english"))]
    
    for kelime in yorum:
        allwords.append(kelime)
    
    yorum= " ".join(yorum)
    derlem.append(yorum)
```

[my variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCfXV.png)

probably i do some easy mistake, could you help me ? thank you

EDİT 1 : when we concad 2 data fareme they keep their orgianal index value. i didnt knew that. i add " ignore_index="false" " and index number noe true

EDİT : i found that my code stop working because of "nan" values. i used fillna operation. and i hope it solves all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually looping over the dataframe using for loops, use vectorization which is faster.

```
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))

yorumlar["Body"] = yorumlar["Body"].replace({r"[^a-zA-Z]": " "}, regex=True)
yorumlar["Body"] = yorumlar["Body"].str.lower()
yorumlar["Body"] = yorumlar["Body"].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
```

Comment: thanks for extra tip. i will think about it. i m a little noob.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem. thanks for helping. i made 2 mistakes

1- i need to use ( ignore_index="false" ) in my concad operation
2- i need to take care of "nan" values. the error is becuse of errors.